# Reverse engineering 18 Bytes protocol

Tags: crc, protocol, spi, communication, checksum

I'm not really used to do algorithm reverse engineering, so I need some help
It's a SPI communication between a STM and a wireless chip, hopefully the data were correctly acquired by the logic analyser

I guess it's a CRC8, data are fixed length of 18 Bytes

[image]

I have already tried `reveng` without success.

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

Comment: With almost zero context and a screenshot instead of text, it's unlikely that this question will yield any answers.  I'd suggest describing the context a little more (like what you know about the wireless chip) and posting *text* instead of a picture of text.